# Modules not showing up in newly created virtual environments using Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, virtualenv

I have Anaconda installed on my mac running High Sierra. A base environment was created and it has around 200 modules installed. I do `conda list` and it lists around 200 modules. I feel confident that in the past, whenever I created a new environment using `conda create -n py27 python=2.7.15`, for example, it would include the same 200 modules. This doesn't happen now. When I use the above command, about 40 modules are included. None of the ones I need are in this list.  Is my human memory the problem or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What 40 modules? No, usually there are about a dozen installed, things like `sqlite` and `tk` and `readline`. And it never automatically installs modules from your base environment. That would sort of defeat the purpose... Are you sure you weren't cloning from an environment file?

Comment: I don't think so since I don't know how to clone. Maybe it's my mind, I am getting old. lol

Comment: I thought the purposes of virtual environments were to allow user to do things like run python 2.7.15 and python 3.6.5 without getting things confused.  At least in my simple mind!

Comment: Well, there is a `-clone` option when you use `conda`, and maybe what you are recalling actually used `clone` instead of `create` (easy to mix up). Generally, virtual environments are to cloister your dependancies. So I'm working on one project which has x,y,z requirements, and another project which has h,f,x requirements, I can have two different environments without the two clashing, or without just creating one big mess in your global environment, with `h,f,x,y,z` installed (what happens when one project requires keeping x static, and the other requires an upgrade)?

Comment: `conda` does make it easy to create environments with different interpreters (I recall this was annoying using `virtualenv`), though. And I definitely keep just a "latest python version" environment around when I want to play with new features so I can advocate for upgrading :)